# What is the length of the cardioid $r=1-\cos(\theta)$?

Tags: polar-coordinates

I know generally how to solve this problem and was able to solve it a week or so ago. However, I keep getting stuck when trying to find $dr/d\theta$. I know that it should simplify to $-\sin(\theta)$ from my notes but I can't get anything other than (1-cos(theta))/sin(theta) when I try now.

Comment: If $r=1-\cos \theta$, isn't $\frac{dr}{d\theta}=\sin\theta$? Isn't that just a plain old vanilla derivative?

Comment: improve formatting like this

Comment: Half angle formula, double angle formula, and various trig identities in every way i could imagine.

Comment: wow! I overthought that

Answer (score 5):

We want 
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{r^2+\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2}\,d\theta.$$
In our case, we want to integrate $\sqrt{(1-\cos\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta}$, which simplifies to $\sqrt{2-2\cos\theta}$.

Now use the trigonometric identity $\cos \theta=1-2\sin^2(\theta/2)$.

Comment: But beware: you will be taking the square-root of a squared quantity, so the result is the _absolute value_ of the square-root of the argument of the radical.  To be safe, integrate the arclength _halfway around_ from $ \ 0 \ \text{to} \ \pi \ $ and double your result.

Comment: Very good general advice! In this case, luckily, $\sin(\theta/2)$ is non-negative in the interval $[0,2\pi]$, so we get deprived of an opportunity to make a mistake.

Comment: I brought it up because there was a similar arclength problem that I was asked about by a student who kept getting total cancellation.  But I also should have looked at your term more carefully because, yes, sine of the half-angle won't cause a problem...

Comment: @colormegone Good advice indeed!